# SQL like query not returning correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am using sql server. I have a table

```
Company
 ABC
 XYZ
 ABC,XYZ
```

When I run a like query `where company like '%ABC%'` I get the record containing only `ABC` and not `ABC,XYZ`

How to get both the records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should not contain comma separated list in one column. Doing so, you will run into issues trying to query the data.

Second, your code should work:

```
select *
from t
where company like '%ABC%'
```

See a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2498/1)

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51af9/1)

Answer (score 1):

select  company from tablename where company like '%ABC%'

it would work irrespective of presence of comma or any other character